# Date query to return all the columns present in two tables

Tags: sql

Here is my query which should return all the columns present in both the tables:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, MiddleName, LastName
FROM 
    Users u
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.CreateTime, 103) > = GETDATE()-1 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.CreateTime, 103) < GETDATE()
     OR CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.UpdateTime, 103) > = GETDATE()-1 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.UpdateTime, 103) < GETDATE()
     OR CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.DeleteTime, 103) > = GETDATE()-1 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.DeleteTime, 103) < GETDATE()
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.CreateTime, 103) ! = CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.DeleteTime, 103)
```

Here are the conditions

1. Report should contain all users added, updated (if user update their FName, LName etc) or deleted since yesterday
2. If the user is added and deleted in the same Day than I should not see the user information in the report
3. If the user is added and updated the same day, then report should contain most recent information
4. If the user is deleted and readded on the same day than report should contain the user information

And the tables:

```
Create Table #Users1 
(
    UniQueNumber Varchar(50),
    FName varchar (50),
    LName Varchar (50),
    CreateDate Datetime,
    DeleteStatus bool,
    UpdateTime DateTime,
    DeleteTime Datetime
)

INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('44354','Kumar','Shruthi-hh','06-21-2016 00:10:000',1,getdate()-1,'06-29-2016 00:10:000')
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('44254','Shankar','Raj','06-22-2016 01:18:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('34154','Babu','Swamy-k','06-23-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('35054','Mani','Kanta','06-24-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('35055','dsfdf','ett','06-25-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('35056','sss','sfd','06-26-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('35057','jkhk','sdd','06-27-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('35058','eer','s','06-30-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 
VALUES ('35059','er','j','07-01-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some parenthesis to separate out your clauses. This will let you evaluate multiple requirements as one overall requirement in your where clause:

```
SELECT  FirstName ,
    MiddleName ,
    LastName
FROM    Users u
WHERE   ( CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.CreateTime, 103) > = GETDATE() - 1
      AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.CreateTime, 103) < GETDATE()
    )
    OR ( CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.UpdateTime, 103) > = GETDATE() - 1
         AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.UpdateTime, 103) < GETDATE()
       )
    OR ( CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.DeleteTime, 103) > = GETDATE() - 1
         AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.DeleteTime, 103) < GETDATE()
       )
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.CreateTime, 103) ! = CONVERT(VARCHAR, u.DeleteTime, 103);
```

In this example everything in the () is evaluate at once, before being used for the OR

In your specific case here though, you can use the between clause:

```
where createTime between getdate() -1 and getdate()
```

Have a play with that.

Just some general comments though:

Can you have things created created in the future that you need to exclude?

Its generally better practice (at least in SQLServer) to use the dateadd function:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,u.UpdateTime ,103) > = dateadd(dd,-1,GETDATE())
```

Converting those date columns to varchar like that is pretty slow. I'd recommend either converting getdate() once as a variable before you start, or if its not giving you an issues, just not worrying about it as the database should be able to figure it out from its collation/language.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you so much for your valuable time,Here when I say yesterday it actually it is not yesterday , its since the report run on last time, this report will be scheduled to run on every day

Comment: This query is scheduled to run on every day Night at 12AM - Monday to Friday. If the query Runs on Monday night than I should get the data for the Friday, Saturday and Sunday dates, however other wise just get the data for the prious date like, If the query runs on Tuesday night than I should get the Monday data and If the Query runs on Wednesday night than i should get the Tuesday data.. similar way it goes on till Friday.....

Comment: 1) Report should contain all users added, updated (if user update their FName, LName etc) or deleted since the report run on last time 2) If the user is added and deleted in the same Day than I should not see the user information in the report 3) If the user is added and updated the same day, then report should contain most recent information 4) If the user is deleted and readded on the same day than report should contain the user information - How I can check this condition, I am not sure about what I have written my Condition

Comment: Updated Query - SELECT u.FirstName,u.MiddleName,u.LastName FROM Users u INNER Join Location l ON l.userId = u.UserId AND u.CreateTime >= dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) AND u.CreateTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) OR u.UpdateTime > = dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) AND u.UpdateTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) OR u.DeleteTime > = dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) AND u.DeleteTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) AND DeletedStatus =1 AND u.CreateTime ! = u.DeleteTime AND DeletedStatus =1

Comment: WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,CreateDate,103) BETWEEN (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,GETDATE()) = 'Monday' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-3,GETDATE()),103) ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),103) END) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),103)

Comment: Can you please correct my query , If am doing anything wrong, because the way 'DeletedStatus' I am using, I am having doubt with that.. Here my main WHERE clause condition is fine, I have already cross checked, basically I need to meet the above 4 conditions, Please help me sir

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName,MiddleName,LastName
FROM 
    Users u
WHERE 
    u.CreateTime >= dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) 
    AND u.CreateTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) OR u.UpdateTime > = dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE()))
    AND u.UpdateTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) OR u.DeleteTime > = dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) 
    AND u.DeleteTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE())
    AND u.CreateTime ! =  u.DeleteTime
```

You don't have to convert dates to string like you did `CONVERT(VARCHAR,u.CreateTime,103)`.
Also you have to use parenthesis to be more specific on `Where` clause.
You got to have in mind that 'GetDate()' returns Date**Time** as your DateTime columns. So you have to be careful when comparing two datetimes. There are NOT just dates.

For example:

```
'31-01-2016' > '31-01-2016 00:00:01' = false
```

**EDIT**

By the way your full example is like this:

```
Create Table #Users1 (
    UniQueNumber Varchar(50),
    FirstName varchar (50),
    LastName Varchar (50),
    CreateTime Datetime,
    DeleteStatus bit,
    UpdateTime DateTime,
    DeleteTime Datetime
)

INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('44354','Kumar','Shruthi-hh','06-21-2016 00:10:000',1,getdate()-1,'06-29-2016 00:10:000')
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('44254','Shankar','Raj','06-22-2016 01:18:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('34154','Babu','Swamy-k','06-23-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('35054','Mani','Kanta','06-24-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('35055','dsfdf','ett','06-25-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('35056','sss','sfd','06-26-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('35057','jkhk','sdd','06-27-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('35058','eer','s','06-30-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)
INSERT INTO #Users1 Values ('35059','er','j','07-01-2016 06:10:000',0,getdate(),null)

select * from #Users1


Declare @nowDate Date
Set @nowDate = Convert(Date,GETDATE())

SELECT 
    FirstName,LastName
FROM 
    #Users1 u
WHERE 
    u.CreateTime >= dateadd(d,-1,@nowDate) 
    AND u.CreateTime < @nowDate OR u.UpdateTime > = dateadd(d,-1,@nowDate)
    AND u.UpdateTime < @nowDate OR u.DeleteTime > = dateadd(d,-1,@nowDate) 
    AND u.DeleteTime < @nowDate
    AND u.CreateTime ! =  u.DeleteTime

drop table #Users1
```

Still you have apply parenthesis to `Where` clause.

**EDIT 2**

Run this in a test database. Is another approach with two tables `User` and `UserHistory`.

```
create table [User] (
    id int not null identity(1,1),
    firstName varchar(50),    
    lastName varchar(50),

    constraint PK_User primary key clustered (id)
)

create table UserHistory (
    id int not null identity(1,1),
    userId int not null,    
    actionType tinyint not null,
    actionDate datetime not null

    constraint PK_UserHistory primary key clustered (id),
    constraint FK_User_UserHistory foreign key (userId) references [User](id)
)

create unique index UIX_UserHistory on UserHistory( userId, actionType, actionDate)

insert into [user] ( firstName, lastName ) values
('tony', 'stark'),
('bruce', 'wayne'),
('clark', 'kent'),
('peter', 'parker')

insert into UserHistory ( userId, actionType, actionDate ) values
( 1, 1, '2016-01-01'),
( 2, 1, '2016-01-02'),
( 2, 2, '2016-01-03'),
( 3, 1, '2016-02-01'),
( 3, 3, '2016-02-01'),
( 4, 1, '2016-03-01'),
( 4, 2, '2016-03-01'),
( 4, 3, '2016-03-01'),
( 4, 1, '2016-04-01')
go

create view UserHistoryInfo as
with insCte as (
    select 
        a.id, max( ins.actionDate ) as lastInsertDate
    from
        [user] a
        left join userHistory ins on ( a.id = ins.userId ) and ( ins.actionType = 1 )
    group by a.id
),
updCte as (
    select 
        a.id, max( upd.actionDate ) as lastUpdateDate
    from
        [user] a
        left join userHistory upd on ( a.id = upd.userId ) and ( upd.actionType = 2 )
    group by a.id
),
delCte as (
    select 
        a.id, max( del.actionDate ) as lastDeleteDate
    from
        [user] a
        left join userHistory del on ( a.id = del.userId ) and ( del.actionType = 3 )
    group by a.id
)
select
    a.firstName,
    a.lastName,
    ins.lastInsertDate as lastInsertDate,
    upd.lastUpdateDate as lastUpdateDate,
    del.lastDeleteDate as lastDeleteDate
from
    [user] a
    left join insCte ins on ( a.id = ins.id )
    left join updCte upd on ( a.id = upd.id )
    left join delCte del on ( a.id = del.id )
go

select * from UserHistoryInfo
go


declare @ckeckDate datetime = '2016-01-02'

select *
from UserHistoryInfo
where
    (
        (        
            ( isNull( lastInsertDate, '1900-01-01' ) >= @ckeckDate )
            or ( isNull( lastUpdateDate, '1900-01-01' ) >= @ckeckDate )
            or ( isNull( lastDeleteDate, '1900-01-01' ) >= @ckeckDate )                
        )
        or ( isNull( lastInsertDate, '1900-01-01' ) = isNull( lastUpdateDate, '1900-01-01' ) )        
    )
    and ( isNull( lastInsertDate, '1900-01-01' ) <> isNull( lastDeleteDate, '1900-01-01' ) )
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you so much for your valuable time,Here when I say yesterday it actually it is not yesterday , its since the report run on last time, this report will be scheduled to run on every day.

Comment: This query is scheduled to run on every day Night at 12AM - Monday to Friday. If the query Runs on Monday night than I should get the data for the Friday, Saturday and Sunday dates, however other wise just get the data for the prious date like, If the query runs on Tuesday night than I should get the Monday data and If the Query runs on Wednesday night than i should get the Tuesday data.. similar way it goes on till Friday.

Comment: 1) Report should contain all users added, updated (if user update their FName, LName etc) or deleted since the report run on last time 
2) If the user is added and deleted in the same Day than I should not see the user information in the report
3) If the user is added and updated the same day, then report should contain most recent information 4) If the user is deleted and readded on the same day than report should contain the user information - How I can check this condition, I am not sure about what I have written my Condition.

Comment: SELECT u.FirstName,u.MiddleName,u.LastName FROM  Users u INNER Join Location l ON l.userId = u.UserId AND u.CreateTime >= dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) AND u.CreateTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) OR u.UpdateTime > = dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) AND u.UpdateTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) OR u.DeleteTime > = dateadd(d,-1,Convert(Date,GETDATE())) AND u.DeleteTime < Convert(Date,GETDATE()) AND DeletedStatus =1 
AND u.CreateTime ! =  u.DeleteTime AND DeletedStatus =1

Comment: WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR,CreateDate,103)
BETWEEN (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,GETDATE()) = 'Monday' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-3,GETDATE()),103) ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),103) END)
AND  CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),103)

Comment: Can you please correct my query , If am doing anything wrong, because the way 'DeletedStatus' I am using, I am having doubt with that.

Comment: Check my 2nd Edit.